# Vue2Leaflet with Leaflet.FreeDraw

Tags: vuejs2, leaflet

I'm using 'Vue2Leaflet' and I'm trying to integrate the leaflet plugin 'Leaflet.FreeDraw'.

Here's how I integrated it:

```
import L from 'leaflet'
import FreeDraw from 'leaflet-freedraw'
const freeDraw = new FreeDraw()
this.$refs.map.mapObject.addLayer(freeDraw)
```

This is the error:

```
regeneratorRuntime is not defined
```

Do you have any tips?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a generator error.
You should probably use babel-polyfill.
npm i -D babel-polyfill

Are you using webpack? If it's the case set your entry point this way :

```
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    index: ['babel-polyfill', './pathTo/main']
  },
  mode: 'production',
  ...
}
```

Hope this helps,

Micka

Answer (score 0):

be sure that **regenerator-runtime** is present in your node_modules/ folder, then import it like this:

**import "regenerator-runtime/runtime";**